# What is the underlying type of Binding used by WCF Data Services

Tags: wcf, odata, wcf-data-services

While creating a WCF data service, we do not have to define Endpoints in the config. What is the type of Binding that it uses, by default? Is there a way we can change the type of Binding being used?

Comment: Which wcf `ServiceHost` are you using?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

WCF Data Services is an extension of the WCF REST services, and thus uses the `webHttpBinding`.

This binding cannot be changed for WCF Data Services  - the whole architecture is so intimately tied to the HTTP and REST paradigm, it won't work over SOAP:

Answer (score 2):

From what I remember, those created with `ServiceHostFactory` use `basicHttp`.

From playing with `WebServiceHostFactory` I could only seem to connect to it with `WebHttpBinding` leading me to believe that is the binding it uses underneath.

It states on: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.activation.webscriptservicehostfactory.aspx  that `WebScriptServiceHostFactory` uses the `WebHttpBinding`

Hope that helped,

Anthony

**EDIT**: This page: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb412204.aspx makes me believe that WCF Web Services default to using `WebHttpBinding`